# Heroku send error time out and multiply files at the moment of deploy

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I had to replicate a site that was very outdated, is created by Themosis. What I want is to deploy it in Heroku, the file compilation process happens successfully but at the moment of entering the site the logs are of an error when not finding the .env file, after creating it through SSH the error it throws is that there are repeated parameters. Not finding the .env file throws a time out error, I know it's a configuration problem but the truth is that my knowledge does not go beyond what I've done.

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: heroku does not upload your .env since its a repo and its in git ignore you should set your env variables in your heroku app settings

Answer (score 0):

.ENV file is not uploaded. You can change it in the Configurations tab, I guess in Heroku it's in the last tab. Edit the configuration variables or environment variables there one by one.